# Moneyfarm (ETF) and Coupons

Tags: etf, bonds, bond-coupons

I am a beginner, I have possessed public debt bonds only, so far. Recently I decided to differentiate my savings on some form of ETF, specifically on Moneyfarm, just to give it a try.
Now, I am trying to understand if the coupons are paid and potentially how they are, in the case of ETF. In my specific case, I have been using Moneyfarm for some months now and I saw that in my ETF wallets there also are coupon bond. How they are usually paid if they are? Thanks.

Comment: As a beginner, the first thing you should do is reading books, go study basic investment (The intelligent investor) and behaviour economic (Thinking, fast and slow;  Misbehaving )  instead of rushing into the market.  As  Daniel Kahneman pointed out that some study show most financial advisors are no better or perform worse than a well-informed investor.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your comment, as I said I am a beginner and I'm studying the field compatibly with the free time I have from my actual job as a software developer. I am not just rushing into the market and I am investing at the lowest risk of the MIFID interview with the only purpose to avoid having a little capital consumed by inflation.

Comment: In "Misbehaving", Richard Thaler has mentioned peculiar behaviour of investing in the bond fund: why invest in the bond that either than 50 years to double or taking high-risk buying junk bond,? When you already know S&P 500 index ETF will not go bankrupt and give you good return in the long run.

Comment: @mootmoot That seems an odd thing to discount. You mention index funds "give you good return in the long run". I always used bond funds much like short term money market, for briefly holding money that will later be used for something else and should not dramatically lose value short term...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coupons from the bonds the ETF holds go into the cash balance of the ETF. From there, it's up to the terms of the ETF whether to pay dividends (which may or may not correspond to the coupons it has received) or to reinvest the coupons internally.

In other words, the coupons that the bonds held by the ETF pay are NOT distributed to you directly.

Answer (score 2):

In the ISA model dividends are reinvested.

Here is the official explanation given by MF itself:

*> Time-weighted rate of return (TWRR) tells the performance of your investments over time. It is used to compare the investment returns as it removes the distorting effects of cash inflows and outflows, even as you regularly contribute to your account.
The money-weighted rate of return includes individual cash flows within a period to give an accurate reflection of the return you receive as an individual. We believe this gives you an accurate picture of the true return you received, accounting for your individual cash flows – these could be dividends, account top-ups or disinvestments. If you were to invest – or disinvest – an amount from your portfolio, this impacts the performance number. You can think of this as your portfolio’s “personal performance”. This measure of performance corresponds to a well-known concept called the internal rate of return (IRR).
Customers often confuse these with a “simple return” calculation, which would be found by just dividing your current value by your net contributions, and over time it will be less helpful as every time you invest you will reduce your performance.
All three measures are in theory the same if you only have one cashflow.*

Source MoneyFarm:
https://www.moneyfarm.com/uk/help/#faqs

In the ISA is specified that: "*dividends are being reinvested, and are performing their best every day*"

A slightly better explanation (even if not complete) of the dividend issue on MoneyFarm is found here:
https://www.revenue.land/moneyfarm

Hope this helps.